# how to add(install) plugin in phonegap 3.0?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I created new cordova project.

but I can't installed plugin

I have been using the following command.

$plugman install --platform android --project . --plugin git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git

And this message was shown.

failed to get the plugin via git from URL git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-dev
ice-motion.git, output: Cloning into 'plugman-tmp1381737348287'...
fatal: unable to access 'git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device-motion.git/':
 Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl

What should I do?

Please tell me.... thank

Answer (score 1):

I think plugman is for version 2.9 or less, instead you should use:

```
$ phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git
```

As shown here:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface