# Not able to install plugin through Plugman in Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, plugman

I am not able to install a plugin through Plugman in Cordova.

I check following links but did not work for me :

- [Link 1](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/w3PAdu0q0R4)
- [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19356108/how-to-addinstall-plugin-in-phonegap-3-0)

Below are the steps that I performed :

- Installing Plugman through `npm install -g plugman` :  **Success**
- Creating a Cordova Project : **Success**
- Adding a Plugin from here : [Plugman to manage plugins](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/plugin_ref_plugman.md.html#Using%20Plugman%20to%20Manage%20Plugins) : **Failure**

Below is the command that I performed :

D:\PhoneGap\hello>

```
plugman install --platform android --project D:\PhoneGap\hello
 --plugin https://github.com/imhotep/MapKit
```

Fetching plugin "https://github.com/imhotep/MapKit" via git clone

**Error :**
*Command failed: fatal: could not create work tree dir 'C:\Users\UserName\App
Data\Local\Temp\plugman\git\1399618229721'.: No such file or directory*

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to install plugin through Plugman.

Below are my steps :

- Created the directory manually : `mkdir C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\plugman\git`
- Then fired the command : `git clone https://github.com/imhotep/MapKit`

  There is a bug in git source dependencies on Windows : https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/895

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

just create a directory with below command

mkdir C:\Users\UserName\App Data\Local\Temp\plugman\git\1399618229721

and use below command to install

plugman install --platform android --project android-mapkit-example/ --plugin /path/to/MapKit --variable API_KEY="YOUR_API_KEY_FROM_GOOGLE"

make sure you have installed latest android sdk and tools

Answer (score 1):

What did the trick for me is to specify exactly the android platform folder...

```
phonegap create foo com.bar.foo Foo
cd foo
phonegap platform add android
```

Now the android folder is in foo/platforms/android/, so the plugman cmd should be

```
plugman install --platform android --project ./foo/platforms/android/ --plugin <pathToBarPlugin>
```

Hope this helps
@phonegap 5.5.1
@plugman 0.23.3